# in C++, how can I find all elements of an array linked directly or indirectly to a specific element of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I have an array of objects, every object has a weight value, some objects are attached to another object who becomes its parent. I need to add the weight of all the child objects to the parent object, also the weight of the objects attached to child objects and so on must be added to the parent.

Here my best approach so far, but somehow it ends up not changing the parents original weight at all:

```
void showMasterClass::mass_manager(int parent)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < total_objects; n++)
    {
        object[n].setMass(object[n].getEmptyMass());
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < total_objects; n++)
    {
        if (object[n].getDockedTo() == parent)
        {
            object[parent].setMass(object[parent].getMass() + object[n].getMass());
            mass_manager_subroutine(n, parent);
    }
    }
}

void showMasterClass::mass_manager_subroutine(int objeto, int parent)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < total_objects; n++)
    {
        if (object[n].getDockedTo() == objeto)
        {
            object[parent].setMass(object[parent].getMass() + object[n].getMass());
            mass_manager_subroutine(n, parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code anyways because it will help us better understand what you have tried and how we can help.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed by your code. People will be more annoyed if there is no evidence you have made an effort to solve the problem, than if your attempt is a bit messy (do format it properly though). And can you give a small example, I'm struggling to make sense of your description. Thanks.

Comment: So your goal is to end with a structure in which each array element has a weight, a parent (potentially null) and a total weight (its own weight plus the weight of everything in its tree of children)?

Comment: How did you implement the parent-child relationship? Does each child contain the index or pointer to its parent? Does the program have to recognize and handle circular dependencies?

Comment: added my code, thanks for the replies. @Frank Puffer Yes, each child has an element that points to its parent. @S McCrohan Yes, that's exactly the goal.

Comment: Look up _Union Find_ algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you're trying to implement is a post-order, depth-first tree traversal. You just happen to be getting your tree in the form of an array with child-to-parent references.

The lack of parent-to-child references is going to make the process less efficient, but it's still doable.

Looking at it purely as a matter of structure (and avoiding code for now, to avoid making assumptions about yours), you're looking at a recursive call that, given the array and the index of a 'root':

1. Finds all of the nodes that have your root as their parent.
2. Recurses with each of those nodes as your new root.
3. Returns your root's weight plus the return values from each child (if any).

If your starting array isn't guaranteed to be free of circular dependencies, then you'll also want to pass down the current 'chain' of visited nodes, so you can return if you ever visit a node for a second time in the same branch of the descent.

To find the child nodes, you can just walk the full array each time. That'll give you an N^2 efficiency overall, which is pretty painful, but it's also the simplest approach to understand, so it's a good place to start. Once you understand how that's working, you can make performance improvements (like making a single pass at the start to map the parent-to-child relationships, which will make the traversal itself faster).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you do not have to deal with circular dependencies:

1. Iterate through the array and mark all objects that are parents.
2. The remaining objects have no children. Iterate through these objects and add their weights to their parents recursively.